# How can I pass on URL parameters to internal links in a Rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-i18n

So I've configured my Rails app to switch language settings using query parameters, such as `localhost:3000/pages/show?lang=en`. Now, how can I pass on this `?lang=en` part to other links included in this application?

I've thought about using cookies, but please kindly let me know if there are other options available.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply pass it inside path or url.

```
<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_user_path(id: @user.id, lang: 'en') %>
```

In above example, I have passed `lang` key with value 'en'